# iOS9 IOSurface background screenshots

Tags: ios9, iosurface

Latest iOS9 screenshots when encountered problems, iOS7 and iOS8 can run success。

I use iPad8.1.2 and iPhone6plus9.1 test, the following is my test the problems found。

[image: iOS8.1.2 Object value]

2015-11-07 14:07:22.849 ScreenRecorder[3292:140825]

**my device info：[iPhone OS,8.1.2,12B440,iPad4,1,prod]**

**(lldb) po framebufferService**

8967

**(lldb) po connect**

IOMobileFramebuffer 0x138031800 [0x1946aec80]

**(lldb) po ScreenSurface**

IOSurface 0x137f00008 [0x1703816c0]

**(lldb) po aseed**

728041

**(lldb) po Width**

1536

**(lldb) po Height**

2048

[image: iOS9.1 Object value]
2015-11-07 14:07:22.849 ScreenRecorder[3292:140825]

**my device info：[iPhone OS,9.1,13B143,iPhone7,1,prod]**

**(lldb) po framebufferService**

24599

**(lldb) po connect**

IOMobileFramebuffer 0x138031800 [0x1946aec80]

**(lldb) po ScreenSurface**

nil

**(lldb) po aseed**

0

**(lldb) po Width**

nil

**(lldb) po Height**

nil

Now problem caused iOS9 screenshots is a black screen。

Who can tell me where is wrong, thank you！

Comment: Please repost your error messages as text in your SO posting, not as screenshots.

Comment: hi @Dai，no crash message，Just iOS9 screen is black，IOSurfaceRef object return NULL